# How to create a preprocessor define for cout that surrounds the string with predefined constants

Tags: c++

I would like to define a macro "BracketCout" that automatically inserts preset string values before or after the stream parameter:

```
#define LEFT_BOUNDARY "["
#define RIGHT_BOUNDARY "]"

#define BracketCout ??????

BracketCout << "123" << "abc"; // outputs "[123abc]"
```

How could that be done?

Comment: I would overload the `<<` operator for string operations

Comment: Don't use a macro but write a function that returns a reference to cout. On destruction of the object just add the closing ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class BracketOut
{
public:
    BracketOut()
    {
        m_stream << '[';
    }

    ~BracketOut()
    {
        std::cout << m_stream.str() << ']' << std::endl;
    }

    std::ostringstream& get() { return m_stream; }

    std::ostringstream  m_stream;
private:
};


int main()
{
    BracketOut().get() << "Hello World";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm already using a log class, implementing Code Clown's suggestion is rather straightforward. Here's a simplified version of the logger class:

```
#define LOG Log().out()

class Log
{
public:
  Log() {}
  virtual ~Log();
  std::ostringstream& out();

public:
  std::ostringstream os;
};


std::ostringstream& Log::out()
{
  os << "["; // beginning
  return os;
}


Log::~Log() // destructor
{
  os << "]";
  std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
}
```

To use it I would call

```
LOG << "abc" << 123; // prints "[abc123]"
```

Comment: Ah dang you were faster! Good one! :)